# Android Studio: Language Defaults are applied instead of Java scheme

Tags: java, android-studio, color-scheme

I've downloaded a couple of schemes for Android Studio. However, after applying the scheme the Java scheme is not used even though my files are *.java and Android Studio draws a little (J) on the icon. The "Language defaults" are used instead which don't provide enough highlighting.

How can I force Android Studio to use the Java scheme? The default scheme doesn't have too many colours, so it's hard to differentiate.

Edit: The project was exported from Eclipse and imported to Android Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution myself. The `src` directory wasn't recognized as `Sources Root`. After I did that the editor magically applied the Java scheme, yay!